# -P option on wget does not work on windows 11

Tags: powershell, shell, wget, curl

If I run:

```
!wget -P ./arcface_model https://github.com/neuralchen/SimSwap/releases/download/1.0/arcface_checkpoint.tar
```

from my jupyter notebook on windows11 It does not recognize !wget, even though wget is installed and recognized by the powershell.

And if I try wget -P from powershell it complains about -P as "Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'P' is ambiguous". I simply want to put the tar file into the directory after -P argument.

If I need to use a curl command instead what would the equivalent be?

Comment: `wget` is a PowerShell alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` in PowerShell 5.1, so to get around that fact, call the full executable path instead of just calling "wget".  PowerShell 5.1 is built-into Windows 11.

Comment: I tried find the path for wget using "path" command in powershell but that command does not work, nor echo $path I have moved from Mac to Windows. I installed wget64.exe as well, maybe I should remove that too.

Comment: If I simply type this in command line "wget https://github.com/neuralchen/SimSwap/releases/download/1.0/arcface_checkpoint.tar" it is downloading. So it recognizes wget but not -P argument!?

Comment: What did you try exactly?  Cause what you have provided currently isn't 
            correct while you are within PowerShell.  The command in your last command is performing `Invoke-WebRequest github.com/neuralchen/SimSwap/releases/download/1.0/…` which is the reason "it's working"

Comment: I tried exactly as I typed in the quotes and seem to have downloaded the right size with an OK status, but I do not see the file name where I invoked the command.

Comment: What you typed is incorrect.  You need to use the full path to wget (with the filename and file extension) in order to actual run wget instead of a `Invoke-WebRequest` command

Comment: I can not find what the full path for "wget" is. Not included in my path, so must be part of system path. Would you know how to find that path?

Comment: The full path to the executable that you downloaded.  `wget` isn't in the system path, since it's NOT installed by default, that would be a horrible location for it.

Comment: the system recognized wget without me installing anything, I have wget64.exe in my download folder but I have not installed anything as yet, there does not seem a need for it.

Comment: Are you sure it recognized wget or did it recognized the PowerShell alias?  You can also do "where wget" but you should locate the full path to the executable.

Comment: where wget returns nothing. when I do wget I get this:   cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Uri:

Comment: It also seem to have downloaded the exact size file I wanted to download, but I do not see that file in the directory where I invoked the command.

Comment: We seem to be talking over each other, you have confirmed, you are NOT running wget from within PowerShell but instead running `Invoke-WebRequest`.  I would just execute `wget64.exe` from a command prompt.

Comment: Yes that would accept the -P option and works. This site, https://techpp.com/2022/03/05/install-and-use-wget-on-mac-windows-guide/ recommends I should put this file inside c:/windows/system32 you think I should do that?

Comment: Of course I don't recommend doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The `wget` command in PowerShell is an alias for a PowerShell-native
command named
[Invoke-WebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2)
that doesn't have these parameters.

Use instead the `wget` product from the Command Prompt (CMD).

Comment: that can work but I am not even sure where the file would go and what it is called. My search for arcface_checkpoint finds nothing, even though it seems download StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK . Is there an argument that I can for the file to go to the location that I want with file name that I want. Any ideas what !wget from jupyter notebook won't work?

Comment: @kevbuntu - The file would be downloaded to the working directory of the command prompt.

Comment: Have you installed the program `wget` and do you know where?

Comment: initially I did not install wget, but I have downloaded wget64.exe which some docs says I should put it inside c:/programfiles/system32, but I do not want to mess with it unless I am sure of it. I think windows 11 comes with wget and curl

Comment: "I think windows 11 comes with wget and curl" - **It does not**

Comment: You should never put anything in System32. Install it in any folder you like, just ensure it's a legitimate version. You may add its folder to the PATH, if you like.

Comment: This is what I got when I type wget without me installing it: cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Uri:

Comment: This is the link  that recommends it putting it in c:\windows\system32: 
 https://techpp.com/2022/03/05/install-and-use-wget-on-mac-windows-guide/

Comment: Ignore it, it's simply bad advice, very bad advice.

Comment: It's not necessary to put wget64.exe in the System32 folder, you can put it anywhere on your drive, then just call the full path to the executable.